# Java + operator behavior not inherited as expected

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods, operator-keyword

I am learning to create classes in Java, but ran into strange behavior.

I want to create a class called `My_class` that has a method called `add`. The method should take a member of `My_class` and add it to another member of `My_class` specified in the parentheses.

E.g., running this:

```
My_class first = new My_class(2);
My_class second = new My_class(6);
My_class answer = first.add(second);
System.out.println(answer);
```

Should print:

```
8
```

Here is the code I am using for `My_class`, but I keep running into problems regarding how `My_class` deals with the `+` operator. I thought that since `My_class` is inheriting from `int`, that there should be no problem, but clearly I am missing something fundamental here.

```
public class My_class {
    /* Data members*/
    private int integer;

    /* Constructors */
    public My_class(int i) {integer = i;}

    /* Methods */
    public My_class add(My_class new_integer) {
        return integer + new_integer;
    }
```

Instead of the expected result I get:

```
The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) int, My_class
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you want to add two ints and not and int and an object. It should be `return integer + new_integer.integer;`

Comment: You've mentioned both `plus` and `add` in your question. Presumably you mean `add` in both places?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message says, you're trying to add an `int` (`integer`) and `My_class` (`new_integer`). You can't do that.

If you want to use the `integer` field from `new_integer`, you have to access it explicitly:

```
return integer + new_integer.integer;
// -------------------------^^^^^^^^
```

(Probably best to rename the `new_integer` parameter to something that doesn't imply that it's an `int`, since it isn't, it's an instance of `My_class`.)

The above returns `int`, so the method would be:

```
public int add(My_class new_integer) {
// ----^^^
    return integer + new_integer.integer;
}
```

If you want to keep the `My_class` return value of `add`, you need to create a `My_class` instance:

```
public My_class add(My_class new_integer) {
    return new My_class(integer + new_integer.integer);
    // ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----------------------------^
}
```

---

Side note: I also strongly encourage always using `this.` when accessing instance members of a class, so:

```
return this.integer + new_integer.integer;
// ----^^^^^
```

It's a matter of style (the Java compiler will infer `this.` where necessary), but IMHO it improves clarity, since `integer` on its own can be a local variable, a class name (though hopefully not), a static member, ...

---

Side note 2: Although you can do whatever you like in your own code, the overwhelming convention (also the official one, [PDF](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)) is to use mixed case with a capital letter starting each word, so `MyClass` rather than `My_class`.